# Using Dependencies or import Module from Github?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I have one doubt regarding using library from **GitHub** to **Android Studio** if anyone help me to solve my doubt, I would be thankful.

My question is
if we want to use **library from GitHub** , we have two option

1. either we can use dependencies to import library in project
2. or we can download the library from GitHub and use it as a module in our project

from above option which one would be good way to use library? (from all perspective)

Comment: The first one. Because you probably won't have time to check and fix the bugs in the future. But, you need to fork the library to make sure you have the backup library in case the original library is removed from the github.

Comment: thanx :D  @ישואוהבאותך

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dependency**

> Because whenever a new version of a library arrives you don't have
> to continuously check and look for it, let your build tool take care
> of that. It can be cumbersome to regularly download and manage
> different versions of libraries. That's where build tools like
> Gradle comes in and informs you about an update and download it for
> you.

Comment: so is it always good to use dependencies ? instead of download the library from GitHub and use it as a module in our project ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use library from github via using dependencies. Why?

- You probably won't have times to check and fix the bugs of the library in the future.
- You need more time to learn about the library nuts and bolts to maintain and update the library in the future.
- You probably don't have enough expertise about the domain of the library.
- You need to catch and recreate the bugs you found in your system. So, you need to keep an exact version of each libraries in your project.
- You can update and change your dependencies easily without afraid of introducing new bugs.
- Make your project clean.